# How can I make Python with Colorama print coloured text after compiling it to an .exe?

Tags: python, cmd, executable, output, colorama

I'm using Python 2.7 with colorama 0.2.5. I'm calling a method, that prints some coloured text:

```
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import Style
from colorama import init


    def sendData(self):
        print("Sending data..."),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        self.browser.submit()
        print(Style.BRIGHT + "[ " + Fore.GREEN + "OK" + Fore.RESET + " ]" + Style.RESET_ALL) ## Prints coloured text

init()
sendData()
```

This part of code gives the user some terminal output in a GUI application (made with pyqt).

Running this script by using the Python interpreter works the way it should on both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. However, when I compile it to one executable file using PyInstaller (using the `--onefile` flag), things change:

- On Ubuntu 12.04, when running the executable from a Terminal, I'm getting coloured terminal output, the way I want it to be.
- On Windows 7, when running the executable from `cmd`, the GUI runs fine, but I'm not getting terminal output.

If it helps, the flags I give along with the PyInstaller command are `-F` (one-file) and `-w` (windowed mode).

How can I get the executable to print coloured text in `cmd` in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is by not using the `-w` flag.